# How to change selected text with a JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, selectedtext

I'm following a course and, in theory, I'm already able to handle POO, `JFrame`, `JPanel`, Event and Layout. I'm in the middle of the Swing components and I'm trying to extend one of the practices made by the teacher.

The objective is to modify a selected text through some JItems. The teacher used JItem to modify the size of the selected text in the same way he did with the formatting and style. In my case, I would like to use a `JSpinner` to control only the selected text. I don't know if I can do this.

I am enclosing the code of what I have done.

```
public class ProcesadorDeTextos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoProcesador marquito = new MarcoProcesador();
        marquito.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

}

class MarcoProcesador extends JFrame{
    
    MarcoProcesador(){
        setTitle("El Palabra");
        setBounds(300, 200, 800, 450);
        add(new LaminaProcesador());
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class LaminaProcesador extends JPanel{
    
    public LaminaProcesador() {
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        //-----2 principle components
        campoTexto = new JTextPane();
        barraTools = new JMenuBar();
        
        //Scroll
        scrollTexto = new JScrollPane(campoTexto);
        
        //---------------toolbar/barraTools-------------
        fuente = new JMenu("Fuente");
        estilo = new JMenu("Estilo");
        configuraMenu("Arial", "fuente","Arial",1,1);
        configuraMenu("Courier", "fuente","Courier",1,1);
        configuraMenu("Verdana", "fuente","Verdana",1,1);
        
        configuraMenu("Negrita", "estilo","",Font.BOLD,1);
        configuraMenu("Cursiva", "estilo","", Font.ITALIC,1);
        
        configuraMenu("", "","", 1,1);
        
        
        barraTools.add(fuente);
        barraTools.add(estilo);
        
        
        
        
        //-------------------Adding principal components----------------
        JPanel Herramientas = new JPanel();
        Herramientas.add(barraTools);
        add(scrollTexto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(Herramientas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    
    private void configuraMenu(String rotulo, String menu, String tipoLetra, int estilos, int tamagnos) {
        JMenuItem elemMenu = new JMenuItem(rotulo);
        if(menu == "fuente") {
            fuente.add(elemMenu);
            elemMenu.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction("cambiaLetra", tipoLetra));
            // StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction ya tiene el método ActionPerformed desarrollado
        }
        else if(menu == "estilo") {
            estilo.add(elemMenu);
            if(estilos == Font.BOLD) {
                elemMenu.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
            }
            else elemMenu.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());
        }
        else {
            JSpinner size = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(12, 8, 24, 2));
            size.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (45,2));
            //size.addChangeListener(new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction("cambiaTamaño", ));
            barraTools.add(size);
        }
        
    }
    
    
    private JTextPane campoTexto;
    private JScrollPane scrollTexto;
    private JMenuBar barraTools;
    private JMenu fuente, estilo;

}
```

Comment: Learning Java and diving head first into UI topics normally is a receipe for disaster. What did you try so far? Do you know how to change the color of selected text - or any other properties? What exactly are you struggling with? How to get the selected size? How to trigger the change? How to apply the size to the text?

Comment: Thank you for your interest Thomas. I have edited the question, although I think it is too long.

Comment: That question isn't too long but proper formatting of the code blocks would be good.

Comment: Btw, `menu == "fuente"` - read up on why you should use `equals()` for objects. That's one of the basics you should get a grasp on before diving into UI stuff.

Comment: True. It happens to me often, I forget the nature of the objects and I usually have failures in the code because of it.

I know that the format is not the correct one, I will try to correct it in these days.

I will try to summarize my doubt in another way. Is it possible to change the size of the selected text in a JTextPane using ChangeListener and StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction? If it is possible, could you give an example? If not, what would be the option?

Comment: I didn't work with Swing in years but if I remember correctly you'd want to use the JTextPane's Document and add the size information there.

Comment: *"The objective is to modify a selected text through some JItems."* By `JItem` (no such thing) DYM `JMenuItem`?